# Iterating through 2d array gives: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I have a function iterating through a multidimensional numpy array and preforming a function on every item in the array, the funtion returns either True or False and I need to filter out all the items which return false:

```
def unhappy_grid(grid, empty_value=-1, threshold=3):
    for y in grid:
        for x in y:
            if happy(grid, y, x, threshold).any() == False:
                print('test')
    return
```

Happy is the function that returns true or false but even after I use .any() it still gives me this error? I don't know what I am doing wrong here, can someone please explain how to fix this?

Comment: Also, this is not necessary, but the if statement can be used like this too: `if True: print("I didn't need ==True! Wow!")` or `if not False: print("Hey... This works too")`. It's a good thing to know; makes the code look nicer sometimes :)

Comment: What gives this error?  Show the full traceback.

Comment: Is the error in `happy` itself?  What's the shape of `grid`.  `y` has 1 less dimension, `x` one less than that.  That means you are still passing an array to `happy`.  `any()` after the call does nothing to correct an ambiguity error within `happy`.

Comment: Omg I found it I am stupid, thank you for your comments because otherwise I wouldn't have thought of it. I didn't think about that y and x would both take 1 argument less.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided an error message, but;

Booleans (True or False) do not have a `.any()` method. If `happy()` returns a boolean, you should check if that is True or False.

Python also has a builtin function called [`filter(function, iterable)`](http://Also%20what%20do%20you%20mean%20by%20%20%20%60Also,%20there%20is%20an%20indefinite%20while%20loop%20in%20my%20script,%20meaning%20it%20is%20not%20getting%20to%20the%20end%20of%20the%20script.%20This%20would%20suggest%20an%20error%20of%20some%20kind,%20but%20it%20runs%20perfectly%20in%20Idle.%60.%20Indefinite%20while%20loops%20don't%20raise%20any%20errors%20in%20most%20cases.) which could be used here.

### Edit:

Oversaw the error in the question title... My bad...

The error apparently arises when attempting to evaluate numpy arrays. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063039/8594404) may answer your question.

Comment: Ok thank you for suggesting filter. I get the same error (see the title) if I just do: happy(grid, y, x, threshold) == False and I checked if happy does return either True or False and when I call it on it's own it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh god, my bad... I oversaw the error in the title.

Comment: Ok thank you for the edit and pointing me in the right direction!